# Nuxt Content async fetch in component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm new to the [**@nuxt/content** module](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/content) and it's working well except **within components**.

Here I'm trying to get the content like so:

*layout.vue*

```js
export default {
  name: 'Default',
  CONTENT: 'content',
  async asyncData({ $content }) {
    const content = await $content('content').fetch()
    return { content }
  },
}
```

*component.vue*

```js
export default {
  async fetch({ $content }) {
    this.content = await this.$content('content', { deep: true }).fetch()
  },
  data() {
    return { content }
  },
}
```

How can I use content within components?

Comment: First note! you can't use `asyncData` in your layout. `asyncData` is just available in pages not components or layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is no reason that `$content` will not work in components, I double-checked. It's just the way `fetch` works in comparison to `asyncData`.

You can read more about the differences here: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/#asyncdata-vs-fetch

But it comes down to a different syntax when using the `fetch` hook, as follows:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch({ $content }) {
    this.content = await $content('content', { deep: true }).fetch()
    // ! it's $content and not this.$content here since you've imported it in the scope
  },
}
```

Comment: Please do not print that kind of code in a comment. Edit and format your answer with the new code/result.

Comment: wups : ) soo it's working now! <3 I tried a few things and I had to remove the deep true part : ) thank you so much!

Comment: No issues, glad it works. Welcome to StackOverflow and enjoy your Nuxt ! :)

Comment: This does not work for me on version 2.15 . I had to use:
`async fetch() { this.$content(); }`

Comment: @OsvaldoMaria either destructure it or call `this` I guess.